# How to generate 5 random numbers in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

How can I generate 5 unique random numbers?

Now I have something like

```
declare v_counter integer;
declare v_random integer;
declare v_result varchar(10);

select FLOOR(1+(rand()*50)) into v_result;
set v_counter=0;
while v_counter < 4 then
    select FLOOR(1+(rand()*50)) into v_random;
    set v_result = concat(v_result,'|',v_random;
    v_counter = v_counter + 1;
end while;
```

The result can look like this:

```
12|22|3|46|3
```

The numbers need to be unique and sorted so it looks like:

```
1|2|3|4|5
```

Any idea?

Comment: This is a typical "you have no idea why you are using SQL" - situation. Still i somewhat like it, to bad its mysql ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your range is small, and you have an [integers table](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/12/07/the-integers-table/), a naive approach might work:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(i SEPARATOR '|')
  FROM (  SELECT i
            FROM (  SELECT i
                      FROM integers
                     WHERE i BETWEEN 1 AND 50
                  ORDER BY RAND()
                     LIMIT 5) sort_these_five
        ORDER BY i) concat_these_five;
```

Comment: since it looks like he's doing it from within a stored proc, then he could just create an integers table as part of the stored proc.

Comment: @Ben, true.  That strikes me as a bit more cumbersome (avoiding name collisions with temporary tables, mostly) than simply adding a supporting table to complement your stored procedures.